# How to convert a Date value to unix timestamp?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

Is there a simple way to convert a Date value to the UNIX timestamp in PowerApps?

For example:

```
UNIX(Today()) // -> 1583722800000
//Or
UNIX(Date(2020, 03, 09)) // -> 1583722800000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can actually just use the Text() function with the format param:

```
Text(Date(2020, 03, 09), "") // -> 1583722800000
```

2. You just calculate the DateDiff from January 1st 1970:

```
DateDiff(Date(1970, 01, 01), Date(2020, 03, 09), Milliseconds) // - Timezone Offset
// -> 1583722800000
```

But be careful as this case will take your timezone in account.

Comment: `""` is being automatically replaced by `"[$-en-US]"` for me, breaking the first solution

Comment: Works just fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use the [ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#ticks) difference:

```
div(sub(ticks(utcNow()), ticks('1970-01-01')),10000000)
```

gives current time in seconds from 1970/01/01.